# Do users have to install non-standard python libraries I imported to run my python exe file?

Tags: python, pyinstaller

If I have a python script that imports non-standard python libraries such as pandas, numpy, etc. and I use PyInstaller to turn it into an executable, will users of the program still have to install those non-standard libraries to run it?

Comment: All libraries should, hopefully, be in ```dist``` folder that pyinstaller creates. So no, end users shouldn't need to install anything.

Comment: Thank you! I was searching around, but I wasn’t able to find a definitive answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As stated in [Pyinstaller docs](https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/):

> PyInstaller bundles a Python application and all its dependencies into a single package. The user can run the packaged app without installing a Python interpreter or any modules. PyInstaller supports Python 2.7 and Python 3.4+, and correctly bundles the major Python packages such as numpy, PyQt, Django, wxPython, and others.

So you should be safe and sound :)